# Look for tools to sync from one mysql to anthother mysql with mixed bin_format

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a tool to sync data online from one MySQL server to another MySQL server, the binlog format of source MySQL server is MIXED.

The tools as I know, such as [tidb-syncer](https://pingcap.com/docs-cn/v3.0/reference/tools/download/), [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html), tidb-syncer need the source binlog format be ROW, pt-table-sync need the source binlog format be STATEMENT.

Answer (score 0):

tidb-syncer is used to sync data from MySQL to TiDB, if you want to sync data from one MySQL to another MySQL why not just use [mysql replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) itself.
And you can change the binlog format if need.

Comment: As some reasons, I cannot configure the MySQL severs, only can connect them.